# Specifying a proxy for a new Ext data ArrayStore gives me an error of no method: 'on'

Tags: extjs, extjs3

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'
>   ext-all-debug.js:6198 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   main.js:1582 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   main.js:2270 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of
>   undefined

For:

```
var ds2 = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        url: 'modules/store.php?method=getAllPages'
    },
    fields: ['value', 'text'],
    sortInfo: {
        field: 'value',
        direction:'ASC'
    }
});
```

If I throw away the proxy setting it doesn't invoke that. Any idea why this happens?

My end goal is actually restructuring the data so it's in the format of:

```
data: [[123,'One Hundred Twenty Three'],
            ['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4', 'Four'], ['5', 'Five'],
            ['6', 'Six'], ['7', 'Seven'], ['8', 'Eight'], ['9', 'Nine']]
```

To feed into the MultiSelect plugin.. whereas right now my data isn't consistent so it only spits out rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you don't want to use shortcuts (recommended), use normal `Ext.data.Store` and model with proxy with reader. You can still pass static data to the store configured this way, however, if you call `store.load()`, request is sent to the server via configured proxy.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayStore do not retrieve data from server. Try instanciate JsonStore instead.

Comment: Then why do ArrayStore take parameter proxy?